# How can I see the CPU utilization of one single process (by PID) on windows 10 command line?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, cpu-usage

When I run the task manager on Windows and look at the processes, I see that one of my chrome processes take up about 15% of CPU utilization and basically blocking all other Chrome windows from functioning properly.

I want to find out what it is and kill it with taskkill command every minute or two. I am not sure what it is and why is it taking up so much CPU time, but it is holding up my work ad killing the process 99% of the time lets all other chrome processes to run normally.

I need to find a way to figure out which process it is.

I tried typeperf command but the output it is generating is devoid of CR/LF to make any meaning to me.

Tasklist command doesn't seem to have a CPU usage column like it has a  memory usage column.
I am stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943928/listing-processes-by-cpu-usage-percentage-in-powershell    ..   Also make sure Chrome is right up to date because Chrome continues to have issues with CPU utilization.  Try Chromium Edge - much easier on CPU.

Comment: When you have the issue, run from an admin command prompt `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` Leave it for 20 seconds then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl`.  Use Windows Performance Analyzer from the Store or WDK, with Symbols loaded to analyze the trace file. Focus on CPU sampled as a start.  Zip and share the ETL file if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- In bat/cmd file:

```
@echo off 

:loop
for /f skip^=1tokens^=1-2 %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe path win32_perfformatteddata_perfproc_process where (Name like '%%chrome%%'^) ^
get PercentProcessorTime^,IDProcess /format:table')do if %%~j geq 15 %__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /PID %%~i /f

rem :: timeout 120 [seconds] = 2 minutes
%__APPDIR__%timeout /t 120 & goto :loop
```

- Or...

```
@echo off 

:loop
for /f skip^=1tokens^=1-2 %%i in ('
%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe path win32_perfformatteddata_perfproc_process where (Name like '%%chrome%%' ^
 ^) get PercentProcessorTime^,IDProcess /format:table')do if %%~j geq 15 %__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /PID %%~i /f 

rem :: timeout 120 [seconds] = 2 minutes
%__APPDIR__%timeout /t 120 & goto :loop
```

- In command-line without timeout:

```
for /f skip^=1tokens^=1-2 %i in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe path win32_perfformatteddata_perfproc_process where (Name like '%chrome%'^) get PercentProcessorTime^,IDProcess /format:table')do if %~j geq 15 %__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /PID %~i /f
```